# How could I reduce my use of switch statements when rendering components based on their type

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, vue.js

I have a array with objects that extend type Component. But the types are still different. So I have for example a SpriteComponent and a ButtonComponent. And the data I receive is formated like this

```
{
    "components":[
        {
            "type":"spriteComponent",
            "imageURL":"https://someurl.com",
        },
        {
            "type":"textComponent",
            "buttonText":"someText"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which I then cast to my own interfaces which all extend from component

```
[
    {} as SpriteComponent,
    {} as ButtonComponent
]
```

My problem is that this results in using a lot of switches. So I first have to look at the `type` and cast based on that. And then with Vue I will have to look at the type again with some sort of switch and render a different Vue component based on the type. Which gives me one component with a giant switch statement to render the appropriate UI for each component.

I could ofcourse make a whole bunch of arrays that all have their own type. But I'm not sure if that is the optimal solution either.

I do have default cases in my switch so my application never crashes but still I feel like I am approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

I would love to get some insights on this.

Comment: Could you post a short snippet of what your component with switch statements look like, i.e. how you use that array in your component? Might help to see how you use it to think of any possible better way to implement it. Off the bat I can't think of how to get away from a bunch of switch options.

Comment: The alternative to a switch is a dictionary that maps from component name string to the component class/function.

Comment: I just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631134/how-to-render-components-dynamically-in-vue-js where you can do :is to render a component based on a label. Looking in to that now.

Comment: How about something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-bouman-io3zw it is quite hacky though...