# how to create a vue3 element dynamic and programatically?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I know how to create one element in declarative way. Ex:

```
<v-btn>hello</v-btn>
```

And i know how to create a bunch of repeated elements in declarative way. Ex:

```
<v-btn v-for="index in 10" :key="index">{{ `hi! ${index}` }}</v-btn>
```

But I dont found a way to create one element in programmatical way.
I just want to do : "**let el = new Element()**"
And then: **DOM.putNewElement(el)**

I dont found how to do this on vue documentation and I want to know if is a "way of be" of vue.
Can you tell me what i'm miss?

I have been try all solution on internet but nothing works

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631134/how-to-render-components-dynamically-in-vue-js . Could be XY problem if it doesn't suit you

Comment: declare the element in your template with `v-if` set to false, then programmatically "create" the element by switching the `v-if` to true.  combine with dynamic components `<component :is=` you then have both dynamic and programmatic creation of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing about Vue that you work rather with [Virtual DOM](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html), not DOM itself, so forgot about manipulating DOM directly. All your templates in Vue are converted into render function that build Virtual DOM nodes.

You can do it yourself, learn in the docs:

https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function

An example:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9kUtPwzAQhP/K4ktaKbRCcCppJR6VgAMgQOLiS0i3qVvHtvwIRVH+O+uEPg6oN+/M59WM3bAbY0Z1QDZhmSusMB4c+mBmXInKaOuhAYvLFFbQwtLqChKiE664KrRyHipXwjQig+QBpdTwqa1cnCXDA+J0hcQMhjCdwWqQfAXvtUpSaLS6k6LYTP68XKL1A9o4qnMZcNimkNwLZ2T+AxU6l5eYDK/j4mzch6WYNHisiPFIE0C2upg1TZerbbMxTZ0qlAke6vNKL1BOOSOfMxj3ZkwYj9n4aBVLmXfUYCnK0dppRU/URJqzQldGUNYX4wU15GwCnRO9nN7g+6nTvA2Y7vRihcXmH33ttlHj7NWiQ1sjZ3vP57ZE39vz92fc0nlvUpEgiT5hvqHTMsSMPXYb1IJiH3Fd2sfuo4UqP9x861G5XakYNJJtx3NGP393ovoh7uXoqrvHVcvaX6yUyO0=)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, h } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

const some = () => h('button', {onClick: () => alert(msg.value)}, 'Display message');

</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg" />
  <some/>
</template>
```

Comment: thankyou! this is exact what i want! I will read about this now!!!

Answer (score 2):

you also can use jsx in your project,it is easy for coding

```
<script setup>
import { ref, h } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

const some = () =><button onClick={()=>{console.log(msg.value)}><button/>
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg" />
  <some/>
</template>
```